# How to move the scroll bar of a HTML table automatically when new content get added

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, html-table, autoscroll

I have a table which grows dynamically with images when I select images from a list. I have put this table inside a div and set autoscroll to the div. I need this scroll bar to move automatically with every new content I add to the table. Is there a function similar to `window.scrollby` which I can use to scroll the div, instead of the entire window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the scrollTop-property of the element to move the scrollbar.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop